# Construir un contenido a partir de varios sub elementos de un array en PHP

Tags: php

En PHP yo recibo un array organizado de la siguiente forma:

```
[1] => Array
        (
            [id_liturgia] => 0000000001
            [antifonas] => Todos los días me sentaba en el templo...
                           |El Señor me ayuda, por eso no sentía ...
                           |El Señor Jesús se rebajó hasta someterse incluso ...
            [ordenes] => 1|2|3
            [salmos_ref] => Salmo 118, 105-112|Salmo 15|Cántico Flp 2, 6-11
            [temas] => Himno a la ley divina
                       |Cristo y sus miembros.. 
                       |Cristo, Siervo de Dios...
            [intros] => Éste es mi mandamiento... 
                        |Dios resucitó a Jesús...
                        |
            [partes] => 5|6|7
            [salmos] => Lámpara es tu palabra para mis pasos...
                        |Protégeme, Dios mío...
                        |Cristo, a pesar de su condición divina...
        )
```

Explico lo más claro posible la situación:

`id_liturgia` es un campo único.

A partir de los otros elementos del array yo necesito construir un contenido que los combina.

Se trata generalmente de tres salmos, pero podrían ser más de tres.

Como ven, cada elemento del salmo viene en una clave del array con un separador interno `|`.

La idea es combinar cada elemento para construir un texto que tenga las respectivas partes de:

- `ordenes`
- `antifonas`
- `salmos_ref`
- `temas`
- `intros`
- `partes`
- `salmos`

El resultado final sería:

> 0000000001
>
> ---
>
> 1
>
> Todos los días me sentaba en el templo...
>
> **Salmo 118, 105-112**
>
> *Himno a la ley divina*
>
> Éste es mi mandamiento...
>
> 5
>
> Lámpara es tu palabra para mis pasos...
>
> ---
>
> 2
>
> El Señor me ayuda, por eso no sentía ...
>
> **Salmo 15**
>
> *Cristo y sus miembros..*
>
> Dios resucitó a Jesús...
>
> 6
>
> Protégeme, Dios mío...
>
> ---
>
> 3
>
> El Señor Jesús se rebajó hasta someterse incluso ...
>
> **Cántico Flp 2, 6-11**
>
> *Cristo, Siervo de Dios...*
>
> [nada]
>
> 7
>
> Cristo, a pesar de su condición divina...

Actualmente lo estoy haciendo mediante un `explode` sobre cada parte y pasando luego los diferentes elementos a una función que los combina. Algo así:

```
function getSalmoCompleto($sOrden, $sAntifona, $sRef, $sTema, $sIntro, $sParte, $sSalmo) 
{
  ....
}
```

Me gustaría saber si **habría una forma más sencilla de hacerlo, sin tener que hacer explode sobre cada elemento** en `antifonas`,`ordenes`, etc y luego pasar cada parte del explode a la función `getSalmoCompleto ()` para que me construya el contenido del salmo.

Comment: @a-cedano lo estas haciendo de la forma correcta, no se me ocurre otra forma que no intervengan `explode ` y bucles

Answer (score -1):

Podés pasar el array y acceder directo a cada elemento del array.
`$arr[0]['antifonas']` por ejemplo para acceder a las antifonas.